# Given several Option<'a> values, is there a well-known pattern for chaining several 'a -> 'b -> 'b functions?

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I have a series of functions `'arg -> 'entity -> 'entity` to update an immutable entity.

I have a series of corresponding `'arg option` arguments where if the argument is `Some`, I should call the corresponding update function.

I have currently implemented it like this:

```
// General utility function
// ('a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'a option -> 'b -> 'b
let ifSome f argOpt entity =
  match argOpt with
  | Some arg -> f arg entity
  | None -> entity


// Function that accepts several option parameters
// (callbackUrl and authHeader are wrapped in option)
let updateWebhook callbackUrl authHeader webhook =
   webhook
   |> ifSome Webhook.setCallbackUrl callbackUrl
   |> ifSome Webhook.setAuthHeader authHeader
```

I like how simple it is, but as is often the case with my homegrown functional solutions (particularly when the generic function is more generic than suggested by the parameter names I came up with), I get the feeling that this is just a special case of a more general functional concept - that I could use some existing abstractions to perform the same task. I therefore wonder:

- Is this a recognized functional pattern? If so, does it have a name, and can I read more about it somewhere?
- If not, is there a (hopefully similarly simple) alternative that accomplishes the same using "well-known" functional abstractions/patterns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just [`Option.fold`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/option.fold%5b%27t%2c%27state%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d) (or more precisely in this case [`Option.foldBack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/option.foldback%5b%27t%2c%27state%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d)). Folds are more generally known as catamorphisms.

```
let updateWebhook callbackUrl authHeader webhook =
   webhook
   |> Option.foldBack Webhook.setCallbackUrl callbackUrl
   |> Option.foldBack Webhook.setAuthHeader authHeader
```

Comment: So, @Lee, in the case of Option what is the difference between `fold` and `foldBack`?  I know for Lists it is the direction of the fold (left vs right).  But what difference does it make for Options?

Comment: @melston - It doesn't really make a different since there's only 1 or 0 items in an option but the order of the arguments is different in `fold` vs `foldBack`: `Option.fold` is `('State -> 'T -> 'State) -> 'State -> 'T option -> 'State` and `Option.foldBack` is `('T -> 'State -> 'State) -> 'T option -> 'State -> 'State`. These mirror the types of `List.fold` and `List.foldBack`.

Comment: Thanks, @Lee.  That makes sense.  I guess I was thrown by the name since most of the languages I have seen up till F# use `foldLeft` and `foldRight` (with the order of parameters to the folder function being reversed).  I saw `foldBack` and wondered if there was something else going on.